# $L^2$ dot product on surface of a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If you have function $M,N:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that are $M,N \in C^{\infty}$.

Can we infer from this that on every surface of a sphere $B(0,R)$ this is a dot product:

$$\langle f, g\rangle := \int_{\partial B(0,R)} f g dS $$

I don't see where this could go wrong, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is unclear as defined since it is unclear what definition of $fg$ you use. I think, you use the pointwise dot product of vector-valued functions. Under this assumption, this is indeed an inner product on the space of vector-valued functions (say, smooth, or continuous or, even $L^2$-integrable) on the round sphere.

However, it is *not* an inner product on functions on the ambient 3-dimensional space, since the axiom
$$
<f,f>=0 \Rightarrow f=0
$$ 
does not hold: A nonzero function can have zero restriction to the round sphere.